# Making a new list in alphabetical order

Tags: python, list

My python instructions are: Write a function called `merge`
takes two lists of strings that are each in alphabetical order.
The function should return a list that has all the strings
in alphabetical order.
The function should return a list that has all the strings in alphabetical
order.
For example, if the function were given the two lists

`[“cat”, “dog”, “pat”]` and `[ “bat”, “hamster”, “piglet”, “worm”]`

it should return the list

```
[“bat”, “cat”, “dog “, hamster”, “pat”, “piglet”, “worm”].
```

Roughly speaking you will start with an empty list to hold the merged list
and an index set to 0 at the beginning of each list.
Compare the first words.  Whichever comes first in alphabetical
order gets appended to the merged list and the index of that list
is increased. Continue until one of the lists is empty and copy
the remainder of the other list to the merged list.

Right now I have the code

```
list1 = ["cat", "dog", "pat"]
list2 = [ "bat", "hamster", "piglet", "worm"]

def merge (list1, list2):
    newlist = []
    newlist = list1 +list2
    final = sorted(newlist)
    return final
print merge (list1, list2)
```

It works, but it's not following instructions. I'm not really sure how to do it with comparing the two lists then appending them to the new list. I also didn't do it with an index set to 0. Can anyone help tweak my code so it fits the instructions?

Comment: if you just need to alphabetize `final`, just use `final.sort()`. Your question isn't perfectly clear.

Comment: @MikeVaughan *isn't perfectly clear*? Of course it is! He clearly mentions that he needs to add the 2 lists and then apply merge sort on it.

Comment: Do we help with homework assignments here? Srsly asking, not trying to be snarky.

Comment: I guess the part that seems... off.. to me is `Compare the first words. Whichever comes first in alphabetical order gets appended to the merged list and the index of that list is increased.`

Why would you ever need to do that if you just want to alphabetize everything in both lists?

Comment: @Dogweather http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: @Dogweather I think we help with homework assignments the same way as we would any other question.  If it's a good question and shows research and so forth, fine.  If poster says, "Do my homework for me," then no.

Answer (score 2):

lets start by writing a compare function

```
def cmp_lists(L1,L2):
    '''returns the first item of the lesser list and the remaining lists'''
    if L1 < L2:
       return L1[0],(L1[1:],L2)
    return L2[0],(L1,L2[1:])
```

now write a method to merge 2 lists

```
def merge(L1,L2):
    if not L1: #if L1 is empty return L2
       return L2
    elif not L2: #if L2 is empty return L1
       return L1
    #otherwise take the first item from one of the lists
    next_itm,(L1,L2) = cmp_lists(L1,L2)
    # and recursively carry on
    return [next_itm] + merge(L1,L2)
```

Comment: I always have trouble with recursive solutions. Good work Joran!

Answer (score 0):

What you have been instructed is to write an implementation for a simple `merge` function that is popularly used in `merge-sort` sorting algorithm.

Since both lists are already sorted, you don't need to join and sort them again. Rather, just loop until one of the lists is empty and keep comparing the first elements of both lists. Pop the shorter element and add to the newer list.

Keep doing so until one or both of the lists become empty. If one of the lists have extra elements remaining, add all of them to the new list.

I encourage you to write the code once again.

Answer (score 0):

Merge sort works by looking at the top elements of the list and putting them in the newly created list.

```
def merge(list1, list2): # assume input lists are sorted
    iter1 = iter(list1) # iterator on the list
    iter2 = iter(list2)
    top1 = iter1.next() # first element of the list
    top2 = iter2.next()
    newlist = [] # new list to fill in
    while True: # loop will exit with break statement
        if top1 <= top2: 
            newlist.append(top1) # put smaller element in new list 
            try:
                top1 = iter1.next() # try to get next element in list1
            except StopIteration:
                newlist.append(top2) # if not, fill list with top2
                newlist.extend(list(iter2)) # and rest of list2
                break # and exit loop
        else:
            newlist.append(top2)
            try:
                top2 = iter2.next()
            except StopIteration:
                newlist.append(top1) # if not, fill list with top1
                newlist.extend(list(iter1)) # and rest of list1
                break
    return newlist
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a merge sort? Oh that's not tough. Just reverse both lists, compare each pair, and pop the loser. Once either list is empty, the remaining list is sorted in ascending order compared to the entire result, so just concatenate it.

```
from operator import itemgetter as iget

def merge(lst1, lst2):
    lst1, lst2 = lst1[::-1], lst2[::-1]
    # popping from the end is MASSIVELY better than popping from the front
    result = []
    while True:
        if not all([lst1, lst2]): # one list is empty:
            return result + lst1[::-1] + lst2[::-1] # so add them both and return
        lst_to_pop_from = min(lst1,lst2, key=iget(-1))
        # gets the list with the smallest final element
        result.append(lst_to_pop_from.pop())
```

```
# DEMO

In [53]: list1 = ["cat", "dog", "pat"]

In [54]: list2 = [ "bat", "hamster", "piglet", "worm"]

In [55]: merge(list1, list2)
Out[55]: ['bat', 'cat', 'dog', 'hamster', 'pat', 'piglet', 'worm']
```

Answer (score 0):

def alphabetize_lists(list1, list2):
new_list = [] # Initialize a new list.
new_list =Aniyahs_list+Imanis_list # Combine the lists.

final= sorted(new_list) # Sort the combined lists.

## Assign the combined lists to the "new_list".

return final

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).